# How to get data from an array and put it on txt file?

Tags: php, arrays, fputcsv

I did a json request to an API REST and got the following result:

```
{  
  respuesta:0,
  marcaciones:[  
    {  
        codigo:18225611,
        codigoFicha:"18225611",
        rut:"18.225.611-0",
        nombres:"CAMILA ANDREA",
        apellidos:"ALVARADO VALENZUELA",
        departamento:"Departamento de Reservas",
        sucursal:"JN",
        fechaHora:"2019-07-22T08:50:57",
        tipo:0,
        numeroReloj:2
    },
    {  
        codigo:18225611,
        codigoFicha:"18225611",
        rut:"18.225.611-0",
        nombres:"CAMILA ANDREA",
        apellidos:"ALVARADO VALENZUELA",
        departamento:"Departamento de Reservas",
        sucursal:"JN",
        fechaHora:"2019-07-22T13:07:11",
        tipo:1,
        numeroReloj:2
    },
    {  
        codigo:18225611,
        codigoFicha:"18225611",
        rut:"18.225.611-0",
        nombres:"CAMILA ANDREA",
        apellidos:"ALVARADO VALENZUELA",
        departamento:"Departamento de Reservas",
        sucursal:"JN",
        fechaHora:"2019-07-22T14:04:04",
        tipo:0,
        numeroReloj:2
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to get all the values of the result and append it to a txt file (one row by result)

Example: (Just the first row):

```
18225611,18225611,18.225.611-0,CAMILA ANDREA,ALVARADO ALENZUELA,Departamento de Reservas,JN,2019-07-22T08:50:57,0,2
```

This is what I have tried so far

```
<?php

    //URL de la API
    $url = 'https://app.relojcontrol.com/api/consultaMarcaciones/consulta';

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    $hoy = date("Y-m-d");
    //Configurar petición en JSON para enviarla vía POST
    $data = array(
        'apiKey' => 'a945fd71f1ac828ac08e22a095ac3448',
        'inicio' => $hoy.'T00:00:00',
        'termino' => $hoy.'T23:59:59',
        'identificador' => [ 
                                //"12.345.678-9"
                           ]
    );

    $payload = json_encode($data);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $result;

    //Transformar para PowerBi
    $output = "resultados.txt";
    file_put_contents($output, $result);
    curl_close($ch);

?>
```

But that just put the entire result in the txt file. How can I get that to my desire format?

Comment: use json_decode , foreach and fputcsv functions.

Comment: You just post your API Key. I recommend that you revoke that if it's a sensitive API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step, convert the json data you got as result from the API with [json-decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
$res = json_decode($result, true);
```

Then open you output file:

```
$fp = fopen($output, 'w');
```

Then, loop on your result and insert the to the file using [fputcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php):

```
foreach($res["marcaciones"] as $e) {
    fputcsv($fp, $e);
}
```

Don't forget close your file at the end: `fclose($fp);`

And then you done.